# How to get all cloud formation exports Boto3

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm confused as how to use Boto3's [list_exports method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.list_exports).

```
response = client.list_exports(
    NextToken='string'
)
```

> NextToken (string) -- A string (provided by the ListExports response output) that identifies the next page of exported output values that you asked to retrieve.

Example response syntax

```
{
    'Exports': [
        {
            'ExportingStackId': 'string',
            'Name': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

What hasn't been explicitly stated is 1/ missing NextToken parameter is acceptable and 2/ the method must be called repeatedly until all values have been returned.

```
def get_all_exports(stack):
    map_ = {}
    client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    response = client.list_exports()
    next_ = response['NextToken']
    helper(response, map_, stack)

    while next_ != '':
        response = client.list_exports(NextToken=next_)
        helper(response, map_, stack)

    return map_ 


def helper(response, map_, stack):
    for ex in response['Exports']:
        if ['ExportingStackId'] == stack:
            key = ex['Name']
            val = ex['Value'] 
            map_[key] = val
```

It works! But this seems like a massive pain. Is there not a simpler approach?

Comment: This is exactly how paginated API calls are meant to be used. Also, it explicitly says that `NextToken` will be `None`: *... If there is no additional page, this value is null.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the tokens as you described, but there are also [paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/paginators.html) added to help with these operations. You will find them usually listed separately under the service heading, under "Paginators". It appears there is one for [listing exports here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Paginator.ListExports). If you do not pass in a config for the paginator, it will page through all of the items.

To use the paginator, you use get_paginator on the client, like this:

```
paginator = client.get_paginator(
            "list_exports"
        )
        for page in paginator.paginate(
            <your code here>
        ):
```